# Modify multi-level dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, multidimensional-array, tree, nested

I want to create a data structure for storing various possible paths through a plane with polygons scattered across it. I decided on using nested, multi-level dictionaries to save the various possible paths splitting at fixed points.

A possible instance of such a dictionary would be:

```
path_dictionary = {starting_coordinates:{new_fixpoint1:{new_fixpoint1_1:...}, new_fixpoint2:{new_fixpoint2_1:...}}}
```

Now I want to continue building up that structure with new paths from the last fixpoints, so I would have to edit the dictionary at various nesting levels. My plan was to provide a sorted keylist which contains all the fixpoints of the given path and I would have a function to add at to the last provided key.

To achieve this I would have to be able to access the dictionary with the keylist like this:

```
keylist = [starting_coordinates, new_fixpoint1, new_fixpoint1_1, new_fixpoint1_1_3, ...]

path_dictionary = {starting_coordinates:{new_fixpoint1:{new_fixpoint1_1:...}, new_fixpoint2:{new_fixpoint2_1:...}}}

path_dictionary [keylist [0]] [keylist [1]] [keylist [2]] [...] = additional_fixpoint
```

Question: How can I write to a variable nesting/depth level in the multi-level dictionary when I have a keylist of some length?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: As you said, this is very broad. Please ask only one question and show what the specific problem is with what you have tried.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I removed the additional questions, is my problem otherwise clear?

Comment: You should probably include some code you're using and tell us what exactly is the problem with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with the idea of using multiple indexes, and a `defaultdict`. And this came out:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class LayeredDict(defaultdict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if isinstance(key, (tuple, list)):
            if len(key) == 1:
                return self[key[0]]
            return self[key[0]][key[1:]]
        return super(LayeredDict, self).__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if isinstance(key, (tuple, list)):
            if len(key) == 1:
                self[key[0]] = value
            else:
                self[key[0]][key[1:]] = value
        else:
            super(LayeredDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LayeredDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.default_factory = type(self)  # override default
```

I haven't fully tested it, but it should allow you to create any level of nested dictionaries, and index them with a tuple.

```
>>> x = LayeredDict()
>>> x['abc'] = 'blah'
>>> x['abc']
'blah'
>>> x[0, 8, 2] = 1.2345
>>> x[0, 8, 1] = 8.9
>>> x[0, 8, 'xyz'] = 10.1
>>> x[0, 8].keys()
[1, 2, 'xyz']
>>> x['abc', 1] = 5
*** TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Unfortunately expansion notation (or whatever it's called) isn't supported, but
you can just pass a list or tuple in as an index.

```
>>> keylist = (0, 8, 2)
>>> x[*keylist]
*** SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<stdin>, line 1)
>>> x[keylist]
1.2345
```

Also, the `isinstance(key, (tuple, list))` condition means a tuple can't be used as a key.

Comment: What does super() do here exactly? I looked at the python docs but I didn't really get what it does... Otherwise I think this is the solution I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: `super(X, self)` binds the `self` instance to the class(es) `X` inherits from. So in this case makes sure that `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` are the methods defined by `defaultdict`, and don't cause an infinite recursive loop.
You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly write accessors for such a nested dictionary:

```
def get(d,l):
  return get(d[l[0]],l[1:]) if l else d
def set(d,l,v):
  while len(l)>1:
   d=d[l.pop(0)]
  l,=l   # verify list length of 1
  d[l]=v
```

(Neither of these is efficient for long lists; faster versions would use a variable index rather than `[1:]` or `pop(0)`.)

As for other approaches, there’s not nearly enough here to go on for picking one.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer, but I don't think this really helps me. If I read the code correctly, this outputs the value for a given list of keys. I want to add elements at that point, I don't think that is possible using an approach like that (I tried something similar, but recursively)

Comment: @E.Staikov: Isn’t adding elements just assigning to a key in the dictionary returned by this `get` for the list of keys up to but not including the one to add?